# Internal server error while processing AJAX request in MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 app, and inside my _Layout.cshtml file, I have something like this:

```
<div class="input-top">
       <a class="GoBtn" href=""><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png" class="gobtn-position"></a>
       <input id="homeZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" placeholder="ZIP">
       <input id="homeService" type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" placeholder="What do you need done today?">
</div>
```

And the point is that when the user fills the above inputs and presses the href attribute, I want to open a new view page and send the data along to the view. The action method to which the view belongs is defined like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ServiceRequest() { ... }

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null) { ... }
```

My rvm view model is defined as follow:

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StateID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a zip code")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a service")]
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    // more unrelated fields below
}
```

Finally, I have my AJAX call, which I have defined between script tags inside my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.GoBtn').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        debugger;
        // Send an ajax post request with data

        var homeZipCode = $("#homeZipCode").val();
        var homeService = $("#homeService").val();

        var model = { ZipCode: homeZipCode, ServiceName: homeService };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ServiceRequest", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: JSON.stringify(model)
        })
            .success(function (result) {
            });
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem is, when I fill those two input fields, and press the Go href, I get an error message saying:

> POST localhost:44300/Home/ServiceRequest [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server
>   Error 4ms]

Any idea what the problem might be? And how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `dataType: 'JSON',` ?

Comment: Have you attached a debugger or looked at the response body to see the details of the error?

Comment: You fill 2 fields but all 3 are required, is that the problem ?

Comment: Since it is a 500 Internal Server error, the error must be in the #C code.

Comment: @christiandev I tried, it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler2 to view the request and response. You can then create new requests in the composer tab to vary parameters more quickly and see the results.

Comment: @SSA Yes, but the point is that I want to open my ServiceRequest view, and in the ZipCode and ServiceName fields I want to have the data presented from the above input fields. The other inputs I want to be empty, and let the user fill them.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be passing `StateID` in the POST data?

Comment: @DavidG But, I just want to open the view, and in the fields for ZipCode and ServiceName, I want the data from the above inputs to be present, then let the user fill out the other fields.

Comment: @Rhumborl http://prntscr.com/4urxea

Comment: But `StateID` is marked as `[Required]`

Comment: @DavidG Okay, I changed it to: `var model = { StateID: 1, ZipCode: homeZipCode, ServiceName: homeService };`, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: And what happened??????

Comment: @DavidG Nothing, everything the same, same error message in console, same output for the debugger, as in the pic that I posted above.

Comment: Then you need to check the full response of the error from the server, so not just the HTTP500 error, but what is in the body of that response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62820/discussion-between-ett-and-davidg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your action method but the AJAX call isn't passing the token through. Remove the attribute and it will work.

Alternatively, you need to include the anti-forgery token in the AJAX POST by putting a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on your page and then including the value this puts in a hidden input.